# How many Devi Sahasranamas are there in scriptures?

Tags: tantra, devi, shakti, shaktism, shakta

How many Sahasranamas dedicated to Devi are there in scriptures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The famous Lalita Sahasranaama of the Brahmanda purana is all too well known.

Quite Interestingly, The Brihannaradiya Purana (Purva Bhaaga, Chapter 89) too contains another different and a lesser known version of the Lalita Sahasranama.

[image]

The Kurma Purana (Purva bhaga, Adhyaya 12) has a sahasranama on devi recited by Himavan.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Few more Sahasranamas dedicated to Devi (Adi Parashakti) are also there.

**Durga Sahasranama from Skanda Purana**

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/DURGA_SAHA.PDF

**Durga (a.k.a Parvati) Sahasranama from Kurma Purana**

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/PARVATI.PDF

**Durga Sahasranama compiled of only those names which begin with "Da" from the Kularnava Tantram**

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/DURGA1000_DAKARADI.PDF

**Kali Sahasranama from Kalikula Sarvasya Tantram**

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/KALI1000_Kalikakulasarvasvam.pdf

**Kali Sahasranama from Brihan Nila Tantram**

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/KALI1000_Brihannilatantra.pdf

And, there can be many more such stotras possibly found in the Tantras particularly for the Dashamahavidyas.

Ashtottara Nama Stotrams dedicated to the Dashamahavidyas though can be found from this page -- https://stotranidhi.com/en/stotras-list-english/dasa-maha-vidya-stotrani-english/